# Как в переменную передать message.text?

Tags: python, aiogram

Переменная **TextMSG** должна содержать сообщение пользователя.

Но выдаёт ошибку **AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'text'**

```css
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="TT1")
async def TT1(message: types.Message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'<b>Введите промо:</b>', reply_markup=nav.FF2)
    TextMSG = message.text.strip()
    if TextMSG == 'Dxx11qeq41':
        await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'+', reply_markup=nav.FF2)
    else:
        await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'-', reply_markup=nav.FF2)
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В первую очередь исправить ошибку в аргументах функции, потому что первый аргумент на самом деле вовсе не message, а `call: types.CallbackQuery`. А вот уже с правильным аргументом через `call.message` можно будет получить доступ к настоящему Message

Comment: у меня в коде есть функции telethon и выходит вот такая ошибка: AttributeError: module 'telethon.tl.types' has no attribute 'CallbackQuery'

Comment: У вас в корне неверная логика. Ваш обработчик реагирует только на текст "TT1". Если вы еще хотите ожидать от пользователя ввода сообщения, используйте FSM:

https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/